# Tag buttons missing from top-right of post

Tags: discussion, tags

There used to be a set of tag buttons on question pages, near the top-right.  I don't remember exactly where they were, but I think to the right above where the information about when the question was asked and how many times it's been viewed is shown.  Here's a screenshot with super-fancy freehand art:

[image: where the tag button used to be]

I noticed that this is no longer present as of recently.  I miss it however, because that is what I always clicked on.  It's also super convenient because it's always in the same place no matter how long the post.  I just had to hit <kbd>HOME</kbd> instead of searching for the end of the question.

A quibble, perhaps, but I can't tell you how much I miss these buttons.

Can we have them back?

Actually I just noticed that these tags are still displayed in meta.  It's in the top-right in a section labeled "tagged"

[image]

Comment: This is currently being A/B tested. Some people will still see them some will not.

Comment: @AaronBertrand:  For me, none of them have them.  Here's a link to the post that provided the screencap above:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21629417/c-3-level-map

Comment: @Oded:  Is the intention to remove these tag buttons?  Put another way, what's being tested?

Comment: Our product manager is better placed to answer that than I am. I am certain he will respond soon.